# Logarithmic equation 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$2\log(x-1)-\log2=\log(x+7)$

$\log(x-1)^2 -\log2=\log(x+7)$

$\log \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}=\log(x+7)$

$\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}=x+7$

$(x-1)^2=2x+14$

$x^2-4x-13=0$

$\frac{Δ}{4}=17$

Have I made some mistake?

Comment: None.$\Delat/4$ is usually denoted $\Delta'$ (*reduced discriminant*). There remains to determine which (if any) root is $>1$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note from the next-to-last line that $$x^2-4x-13 = (x-2)^2-17$$

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Your solution seems to be correct.

But do ensure that the values you get for $x$ after solving satisfies the domain on question, which is $x>1$.